# How do you draw the plane on which two vectors lie?

Tags: graphics

Given two arbitrary vectors $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{v}_2$, how can I draw the plane which they span?

Comment: To give a mathematical viewpoint: both Mark's and David S.'s approaches use the [Hessian normal form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html) of a plane. I would say that if you're trying to do anything mathematical in *Mathematica*, MathWorld is one of those places you should try looking for formulae in...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[3];
{v1, v2} = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2, 3}];
n = Cross[v1, v2];
Show[{
  ContourPlot3D[n.{x, y, z} == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False],
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}]}]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
v1 = {1, -1/2, -1.9}; (* pick something *)
v2 = {0, 1, -1}; (* pick something *)
r0 = {-1/2, 1/2, 3/4}; (* point in the plane; pick something *)

nn = Normalize[Cross[v1-r0, v2-r0]];
r = {rx, ry, rz};
sol = Solve[Dot[nn, (r - r0)] == 0, {rz}] // Simplify
Plot3D[rz /. sol, {rx, -10, 10}, {ry, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely much better than my idea.

Comment: It seems you've misapplied the formula for the Hessian normal form here. `(rz - Last[v1] /. First[Solve[Dot[nn, (r - r0)] == 0, {rz}]]) /. Thread[{rx, ry} -> Take[v1, 2]]` ought to be yielding `0`, but it doesn't, and similarly for the version where `v1` is replaced by `v2`. There is a simple fix: use `nn = Normalize[Cross[v1 - r0, v2 - r0]];` instead for computing the normal vector.

Comment: @J.M. You are, of course, correct--thanks for the correction! I am fixing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use `Graphics3D` primitives

```
Graphics3D[Polygon[{{0,0,0},v1,v1+v2,v2}]]
```

**Edit**

J.M. already gave one way to produce a square spanned by the two vectors as a `Polygon`. Another way would be to use `Rotate`:

```
{v1, v2} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}]

Graphics3D[{
  Rotate[Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}],
    {{0, 0, 1}, Cross[v1, v2]}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: just ahead of me again! serves me right for trying to put a nice texture on it...

Comment: @acl Blame David Zaslavsky. I was busy typing a ParametricPlot3D solution but had to switch tactics when  his solution popped up.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant

Comment: The problem with this method (and mine as well) is that you don't get the whole plane, only the piece of it that is directly _bounded_ by the given vectors. So while it is elegant, I think you're answering something a little different from what the question is actually looking for.

Comment: @acl at least it's the shortest.

Comment: @David on the other hand, you can't actually *draw* the whole plane spanned by them, as the question asks :)

Comment: @acl: heh, true :-) Naturally, I meant that with this solution and mine, the bounds of the region of the plane which is rendered need to be set separately from the bounds of the plot region, as opposed to Mark's and (other) David's solutions which automatically plot as much of the plane as will fit in the specified axes.

Comment: Of course, one could modify Heike's approach (which is important since you effectively use just one `Polygon[]` for your plane) by orthogonalizing and then multiplying your now-orthogonal vectors with a scale factor.

Comment: @J.M. The number of Polygons used in for example David Skulsky's solution can be reduced quite a bit by setting `PlotPoints->2, MaxRecursion->1`.

Answer (score 7):

If your vectors are three-element lists, here's one way (though I really feel like a hack for suggesting this):

```
ParametricPlot3D[u v1 + v v2, {u,-1,1},{v,-1,1},
  PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},Automatic}]
```

You may have to adjust the limits of -1 and 1 depending on how much of the plane you want to plot.

Answer (score 7):

I present here a modification of Heike's approach that might be attractive for some applications; it produces a square with side length `c` as a `Polygon[]` object, representing the plane spanned by `v1` and `v2`, with origin at `r0`:

```
v1 = {1, -1/2, -19/10}; v2 = {0, 1, -1}; (* spanning vectors *)
r0 = {-1/2, 1/2, 3/4}; (* origin *)
{o1, o2, o3} = Orthogonalize[Append[#, Cross @@ #]] &[{v1 - r0, v2 - r0}];
With[{c = 6}, (* generate a c×c square *)
   Graphics3D[{{Directive[EdgeForm[], Gray], 
      Polygon[{r0 + c (o1 + o2)/2, r0 - c (o1 - o2)/2, 
               r0 - c (o1 + o2)/2, r0 + c (o1 - o2)/2}]},
              {Red, Arrow[{r0, v1}], Arrow[{r0, v2}]},
              {Blue, Arrow[{r0, r0 + Cross[v1 - r0, v2 - r0]}]}},
              Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: square spanned by vectors]

As can be seen from the code, the trick is in producing mutually orthogonal unit vectors via `Orthogonalize[]` (for older versions, use `QRDecomposition[]` instead and take the $\mathbf Q$ factor) that can be nicely scaled/combined afterwards.

Here's how to verify that a square is indeed produced as claimed:

```
FullSimplify[Map[Norm, Differences[Append[#, First[#]]]]&[{r0 + c (o1 + o2)/2, 
             r0 - c (o1 - o2)/2, r0 - c (o1 + o2)/2, r0 + c (o1 - o2)/2}], c > 0]
{c, c, c, c}
```

Answer (score 5):

Interactive - drag orange dots around.

```
Manipulate[ Graphics3D[{{Blue, Opacity[.5], Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, 
{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}]}, {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{p, 0}}]}, 
{Black, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, Flatten@{q, 0}}]}}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> .37],{{p, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1},{1, 1}},{{q, {0, 1}}, 
{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
v1 = {1, -1/2, -19/10}; v2 = {0, 1, -1}; (* spanning vectors *)
r0 = {-1/2, 1/2, 3/4}; (* origin *)
```

as a concrete example, I present here, for giggles, variations of [Mark's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1460) and [David Skulsky's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1458) answers, based on formula 18 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html).

**Mark:**

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[
  Det[PadRight[{{x, y, z}, r0, v1, v2}, {4, 4}, 1]] == 0, {x, -3, 
   3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrow[{r0, v1}], Arrow[{r0, v2}]}, {Blue, 
    Arrow[{r0, r0 + Cross[v1 - r0, v2 - r0]}]}}]]
```

[image: plane spanned by vectors, ContourPlot3D[] version.]

**David (plus Heike's suggestion):**

```
Show[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[z /. 
    First[Solve[
      Det[PadRight[{{x, y, z}, r0, v1, v2}, {4, 4}, 1]] == 0, 
      z]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1, Mesh -> 0, PlotPoints -> 2], 
 Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrow[{r0, v1}], Arrow[{r0, v2}]}, {Blue, 
    Arrow[{r0, r0 + Cross[v1 - r0, v2 - r0]}]}}]]
```

[image: plane spanned by vectors, Plot3D[] version.]

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
{v1, v2} = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2, 3}];

Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}]}, 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, v1, v2}], 
 ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Green], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

If vectors are no parallel, you can get a nice orthonormal basis for the plane so you can control the plane sides.

```
v1 = {1, -1/2, -19/10}; v2 = {0, 1, -1};(*spanning vectors*)

{u, v} = Orthogonalize[{v1, v2}];
Graphics3D[{(*Plane*)
  First@ParametricPlot3D[t u + s v, {t, -1, 2}, {s, -3, 2.5},
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4], Gray}],
  (*First@ParametricPlot3D[t v1 + s v2, {t, -1, 2}, {s, -3, 2.5},
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4], Gray}],*)
  (*Vectors*)
  Arrowheads[{0.06}], AbsoluteThickness[3.5],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}], Orange, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}]
  }, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {3, 0.09, 1.3}]
```

[image]

Or simply  you can draw an paralelogram

```
   v1 = {1, -1/2, -19/10}; v2 = {0, 1, -1}; or3 = {0, 0, 0};
    Graphics3D[{(*Plane*)
      EdgeForm[Thin], 
      FaceForm[{Gray, Opacity[0.1]}], Polygon[{v1, or3, v2, v1 + v2}],
      (*Vectors*)
      Arrowheads[{0.06}], AbsoluteThickness[3.5],
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}], Orange, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}]
      }, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {3, 0.09, 1.3}]
```

[image]