# Show that three given vectors lie on a line, a plane, or span 3-space

Tags: graphics, vector

Given three vectors, `{2, 0, 0}`, `{0, 2, 2}`, `{2, 2, 3}`, how could I see if they are all on the the same line, plane, or all of r3 in *Mathematica*?  I can graph them all, like:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}};
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ data]
```

but how can I say take two of them, draw a plane from them, and visually see the 3rd vector in relation to the plane?

Comment: You want to do this visually or it's about linear algebra? If the former case than check `RegionPlot3D` and try to use it plot area that is perpendicular to the cross of two given vectors... unless they are parallel.

Comment: here, take a look: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1457/5478

Comment: If by "see" you mean "determine" then you can use `MatrixRank`. For your example, `In[12]:= MatrixRank[data]

Out[12]= 2`

Comment: Yeah, I would like to be able to show it visually.

Comment: Thanks Kuba.  I saw that but didn't realize it was my answer!  v1 = {2, 0, 0}
v2 = {0, 2, 2}
n = Cross[v1, v2];
Show[{ContourPlot3D[
   n.{x, y, z} == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False], 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v1}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, v2}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}]}]}]

Answer (score 1):

You can visually demonstrate that the vectors the vectors lie on a line in 3-space (and, *a fortiori*, are coplanar) by adding a line drawn from `data[[1]]` to `data[[3]]` to your `Graphics` expression.

```
With[{data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}}}, 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ data], Line[{data[[1]], data[[3]]}]}]]
```

[image: vectors]

Comment: But for assuring (visual) coplanarity two different perspectives would have to be shown, no? The image as shown above does not ensure coplanar vectors.

Comment: @YvesKlett maybe but it's 3D, feel free to drag and rotate :)

Comment: @Kuba agreed. One way to automatically show coplanarity would be to choose the view direction parallel to the given plane ;-)