# Generating plane equation from LinearSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, linear-algebra

I will ask a simple question and might have an issue on the site that explains better about it, but not found.

I am formulating a code that defines me an equation that I can generate a plot.

```
m = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}};
b = {1, 2, 3};
abc=LinearSolve[m, b]
f=abc[[1]]*x+ abc[[2]]*y+ abc[[3]]*z
sol=Solve[f==0,z]
Plot3D[sol,{x,0,15},{y,0,15}]
```

Or

```
Plot3D[z,{x,0,15},{y,0,15}]
```

I'm realizing that there is a mistake, but I do not know how to get an equation from LinearSolve output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Solve` is one of the functions that returns a list of rules and you need to use the `/.` Replace All command. Read: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505

```
m = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}};
b = {1, 2, 3};
abc = LinearSolve[m, b]
f = Dot[abc, {x, y, z}]
sol = Solve[f == 0, z]
Plot3D[z /. sol, {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

And as J.M. mentioned `f=` [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) `[abc, {x, y, z}]`is the same as `f = abc[[1]]*x + abc[[2]]*y + abc[[3]]*z`

Comment: You can use `Dot[]` to form the equation, of course.

Comment: Really! Sometimes the answer is so easy that does pass shame.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho  No worries. Glad to help.

Comment: I would get another plane forming an angle of 50 ° with this plane and had the point {1, 1, 1} and the point {1, 2, 3} in common

Comment: I do not have a diagram. I imagined getting through a rotation matrix

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html

Comment: @Leandro, you know `RotationMatrix[]` is built-in, no? Do you know how to work with the Hessian form of a plane?

Comment: I know, but I can not use it to get the equation of another plan that I want to get

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-you-draw-the-plane-on-which-two-vectors-lie

Comment: I do not know this Hessian form.

Comment: "I do not know" - it was a hint for you to search the terms in a fabulous search engine, @Leandro.

Comment: I am Brazilian and sometimes I do not understand what you are writing

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html

Comment: @J.M. I think now I understand what you mean

Comment: @Young The link you left helped me a lot

Comment: To skip `Solve[]` altogether: `sol = Expand[-Most[abc].{x, y}/Last[abc]]`.